# when i am adding new product or modifying the record it is not showing the result set in search after building index in django oscar

Tags: python, django, solr, django-oscar

As I used Solr for search backend, and once my product get index and now the second time when I add new products and change price after index created that product not being search in and sorting of price also not worked for new change ( i need to rebuild index then start the java server then will work properly ), is there any other solution for the same . I am using Solr 4.7.2.

Comment: Have you checked the Solr log to see if django attempts to update the product?

Comment: No changes happen to Solr log when adding or changing the product name and product price from Django-oscar Dashboard. and the new changes does not appear in search , is i am missing something or i have t rebuild index again and again when there is any change happen ,

Comment: I'm not talking about changes - I'm talking about whether the change is _submitted_ to Solr. You can see this in the Solr log if you set it to the INFO level. This will help you identify _where_ the problem might be. If Solr never receives the update, it might a django issue with the save hooks. If Solr receives the update, but never receives a commit - it might an issue in the Solr adapter for django, or if it both receives the update and a commit, it's a Solr issue. My guess is that the update never arrives.

Comment: What signal processor are you using? You should use a custom one, or at the very least the `RealtimeSignalProcessor` from haystack. Read more - http://django-haystack.readthedocs.io/en/latest/signal_processors.html#realtime-realtimesignalprocessor